# Deletando registros filhos com anotação @ManyToOne do Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-jpa

Tenho as classes `Presente` e `Reserva`, conforme abaixo:

```
@Entity 
public class Presente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;

    private String nome;
    //getters e setter omitidos
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Reserva {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;

    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Presente presente;
    //getters e setter omitidos
}
```

A inserção de ambos os registros funciona e consigo reservar um presente. Preciso que, ao excluir um presente, as reservas associadas também sejam excluídas, porém mesmo com o mapeamento acima e com o `cascade` eu recebo a mensagem de **erro** dizendo:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`presente`.`reserva`, CONSTRAINT `FKkrcm39i10icgcfw703oi79tbr` FOREIGN KEY (`presente_codigo`) REFERENCES `presente` (`codigo`))

Sei que a mensagem é devido a integridade do banco, mas o `JPA` não deveria tratar esse comportamento, deletando as reservas antes de deletar o presente?
O que preciso alterar?

Comment: publique o método de exclusão do `Presente`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que você está tentando excluir um registro que é relacionado em outra tabela. Pela forma do seu relacionamento, sendo unidirecional, você deve remover o *presente* da lista das reservas que estiver associado, atualizar esta lista de forma que o mesmo fique *orfam* antes de excluir o presente.

Para usar a JPA, se você alterar o relacionamento para **OneToMany** ou criar o relacionamento bidirecional para **ManyToOne** terá o resultado esperado. Com JPA deverá fazer uso conjunto dos métodos **clear** e **remove** do EntityManager.

```
@Entity 
public class Presente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;

    private String nome;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "presente", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
   private Set<Reservas> reserva;
}
```

se for usar o hibernate:

```
@Entity 
public class Presente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;

    private String nome;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="presente", orphanRemoval=true)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private List<Reserva> reservas;
}
```

Se permitir que o hibernate gerencio o schema da sua base você pode usar

```
@Entity
public class Reserva {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;

    private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Presente presente;

 }
```